# Using Scrapy 1.6.0 got DEBUG: Crawled (200)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and try to crawl from different pages.

Following is based on Selenium. It will crush after 100 pages and the speed is 1 page per second. I think it may be the website limitation. To avoid it, disable cookies or use fake header maybe work. I didn't try it up to now. I really need some great advices.Thank you so much!

```
class test1113(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "chrome"

    def __init__(self):
        chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
        chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chrome\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chromeOptions)
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chrome\chromedriver.exe')

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.emsc-csem.org/Earthquake/?view=1'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next_page = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('*[alt="Next page"]')[0]
            try:
                tables = response.xpath('//table')
                table = tables[3]
                rows = table.xpath('//tr[@id]')
                for row in rows:
                    temp = row.xpath('td//text()').extract()
                    if (12 == len(temp) and temp[0] == 'earthquake'):
                        yield {
                            'time:': ' '.join(temp[1].split()),
                            'latitude:': ' '.join((temp[3] + temp[4]).split()),
                            'longitude:': ' '.join((temp[5] + temp[6]).split()),
                            'depth:': ' '.join(temp[7].split()),
                            'magnitude:': ' '.join(temp[9].split()),
                            'region:': ' '.join(temp[10].split()),
                            'update time:': ' '.join(temp[11].split()),
                        }
                        print('time:', ' '.join(temp[1].split()))
                next_page.click()
            except:
                break
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that isn't an error, Scrapy is indeed working fine.

The main problem I can see here is that content on that webpage needs some time to load, so your script will need to wait, and you can achieve that by using Selenium or Splash.

My advice would be to use Splash, it was developed for use with Scrapy, so here are some leads that will help you.

> Official GitHub repository of Scrapy-Splash:
>   https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash
>
> Docs: https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html
>
> And here is an example of the integration of Splash with Scrapy:
>
> https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because of my system limitation, I can not use docker, so I tried Selenium. However, the speed is really slow, like 1 page per second some thing. And the program will crush after more than 100 pages. I think maybe I need to use fake header and disable cookies to avoid the website restriction. Up to now, I can not implement my ideal. So, can you give me more advices？Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, regarding the speed of Selenium do not expect much it was built for testing purposes, not for web scraping. And for the crashes they are mostly because Selenium has some internal bugs, so you will need to research it a bit more how to overcome them. But if you want to stay low and do not get blocked you will need to use some proxies, I would suggest as many Scrapy Developers use, ScrapingHub, you can use their Crawlera, so you can host your spider on their servers and they will do the rest !

Comment: PS: Crawlera via ScrapingHub is paid service, so if you building some business that will depend hugely on your data extraction you can't get wrong with it. If you are doing for learning purposes ScrapingHub is included in GitHub Student Pack, so you can host your Scrapy Spider for free on their servers, but you have limited crawling time and data storage.

Comment: And if you think my answer has helped you solve your problem, please select it as an answer to this question!